# generating matrices with random entries in [0,1) in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm working in python and using numpy. I'm using the command:

```
numpy.random.random_sample((n,n))
```

to generate matrices with random values between (0,1). My understanding is that this function should select x $\in$ (0,1) with uniform probability distribution as opposed to say, normal distribution. Can anyone confirm if this I am using it correctly?

Comment: Maybe you could type it in your desktop, and check either it output what you want? well, that is how I usually do to test my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it looks right.  Except technically it generates values with the half-open interval [0, 1).  That is, it's possible to return 0 but not possible to return 1.  For almost all applications this is negligible since the probability of returning 0 or 1 is almost 0.

Comment: If you want to type less, `numpy.random.random` is an alias to the same function.

Comment: probability of zero is ~`2**-53` so indeed unlikely to see zero in any reasonable amount of time (would be a month or two of solidly generating these on my laptop)